# generics using where to limit to base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method:

```
private double FindPrice<T>(T l_Price_Breaks) where T : ?
{
}
```

The `?` I want to limit to 3 classes X, Y, Z.  These three classes inheric from a class called child:

```
public class X : Child
public class Y : Child
public class Z : Child
```

Can't I just do :

```
private double FindPrice<T>(T l_Price_Breaks) where T : Child  
{
}
```

It works but when I try to call this method using the following:

```
X MyX = new X();
double return = FindPrice(MyX);
```

I get "There is no implicit conversion from X to Child".

Comment: If the compiler says there's no conversion from `X` to `Child` then I'm sure it's right. If you could post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would help. (The code you've posted isn't valid - you've used `Public` instead of `public` twice, and you've tried to use `return` as an identifier.)

Comment: even after fixing the syntax, no repro with the given sample - this should work just fine.

Comment: Having a base class called `Child`... that's just wrong.

Comment: Kobi, relax.  I don't name things this way.  I just wanted to make it as easy as possible for the readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me with one exception: You have a variable name called `return`, which does not work, since this is a reserved keyword in c#. Rename it to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have another bunch of problems with your code, like

> Identifier expected; 'return' is a keyword.

`Public` needs to be `public`, etc.

If you rewrite your code like this

```
class GenericTest
{
    public class Child { }
    public class X : Child { }
    public class Y : Child { }
    public class Z : Child { }


    private double FindPrice<T>(T l_Price_Breaks) where T : Child
    {
        return 2;
    }

    private void foobar()
    {
        X MyX = new X();
        double retValue = FindPrice(MyX);
    }
}
```

It compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some essential information like the implementation of `FindPrice`, but I'll take a guess that you're using `Child` instead of `T` in the body of the `FindPrice` method.